# After Effects: How to do line animation on a moving camera

Tags: after-effects

I've got a drone shot of an area where there will be built a road in the future. The drone shot is a simple pan to the left and I want to draw where the future road will be built with line animation.

I've got the shot camera tracked, but I'm having problems figuring out where and how to put the line animation when there are points that will at different times be on or outside the current camera view.

Btw: I'm trying to do this in After Effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After more research I found the solution myself:

I created a null track layer from the camera tracker data, then a new shape layer. The shape layer then needs to be a 3D-layer and then linked to the null track layer. Once that was in place I was able to draw the path I needed and then animate it.